# Unpack a value and use part of it as a given

Tags: scala, given

I have code like this:

```
def foo(using s: String) = ???

case class S(s: String)

val value = S("some string")
value match {
  case S(str) =>
    given s: String = str
    foo
}
```

Is there a way to declare the variable used in the unpacking (`str`) as given, rather than creating an explicit reference to it on the next line.

The best that I've found so far is

```
  case S(str) =>
    given String = str
```

which lets me at least avoid having a second name for the variable, but it would be nice to get it all into one line.

The real code uses a more distinctive type, so any problems related to using a very common class (`String`) as a given are artifacts of making a minimal example

Comment: (Opinion) I would choose your original code, easy to read and understand by anyone. Rather than some weird syntax just to save one line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pattern match givens with the pattern `<identifier> @ given <type>`, like this:

```
value match {
  case S(str @ given String) => foo
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another solution:

```
value match {
  case S(str) => foo(using str)
}
```